# Can I move the range hood but not the roof vent (angled "flue" pipe)?

Tags: vent, stove, hood

I have a typical 30" stove installed in the center of a 20' wall with a standard overhead hood that looks a lot like this.

[image]

I want to redesign my kitchen with new cabinets so the stove becomes corner mounted (45 angle) which means moving the stove about 9 feet along the wall (towards the center of the house) into the corner so it would look like this.

[image]

Is there any reason other than maybe local (Los Angeles County) codes (I haven't checked yet) that I couldn't or shouldn't reroute the hood ("flue" ?) pipe at an angle so it meets the existing roof vent from the new "starting" position instead of a straight vertical pipe?

Comment: Local code will stipulate the maximum horizontal to vertical ratio for the flue to prevent condensation etc cooling in the vent and dripping back down, and for this reason you won't want a totally horizontal section it will need some grade on it

Comment: Length of the pipe, and number of bends will also have to be taken into account.

Answer (score 4):

Putting the stove in the corner like you propose also gives you some nice space to work with for routing the pipe up into the ceiling / roof area or out an exerior wall.

Seems to me that re-routing the vent to the previous riser location is a total non-starter. Many hoods vent up into the small cabinet above the hood and your re-routed vent pipe is going to make a mess of the upper cabinets if it has to route nine feet across your kitchen.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is enough information provided in your question to absolutely answer this, as well, we try and stay away from location-specific codes on this site.

As Tester101 mentioned, whether you can re-use the existing vent will depend on the distance as well as the size of the vent and the number of bends.  The capacity of the hood will also play into this.

If your range is against an exterior wall, you might consider a unit that will direct-vent behind it to outside.  Cutting a single hole to vent it might be easier than trying to re-route the entire vent.  One the outside you install a wall vent like this:

[image: Vent Hood]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.ca](https://www.homedepot.ca/wcsstore/HomeDepotCanada/images/catalog/10263.PMH4WZW_4.jpg))</sub>